# Android app crashes after setConnectionTimeout

Tags: java, android, apache, wamp

I want to implement a setConnectionTimeout in my Android app. I've followed several code structures but couldn't make it work. My app was connected to a localhost server, I just want it to display Connection Timeout if it cannot be connected to the database.

Here is my Http Request code:

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
// Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
// The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used. 
int timeoutConnection = 3000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
// Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
// in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
int timeoutSocket = 5000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

// defaultHttpClient
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

The problem is when it reaches 3 seconds, the app crashes. Before I implemented this snippet, it just freezes for a longer time. And if I turn off my Wifi, it will return a DialogBox saying that the internet is not connected, and this is what I want to achieve.

Any idea how to return an AlertDialogBox if database couldn't be connected? (I've disabled WAMP for this purpose)

Comment: post your logcat for the crashlog.

Comment: Here is the logcat: http://pastebin.com/pS70UDe9

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is saying that there's a null pointer exception while parsing JSON. You didn't attach that code here, so I'm only assuming that once your timeout occurs, you're still trying to parse the input stream into JSON.

It would be good to check if your input stream isn't empty first.

Comment: Excuse my beginner-ness, but could you tell me where the code is and how to check if my input stream is not empty and make it empty?